# adding javascript signature pad in .php file

Tags: javascript, php, payment-processing, electronic-signature

I have a .php file that once a transaction is approved, I want it to show the signature pad but how will I implement it into my php code. The code below is a part of the .php file and I need to get https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad this signature pad to show but it is in JavaScript.

```
 if($tran->result == "Approved"){

}
```

d

```
if($tran->result == "Approved"){
?>



<?
echo '<canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" width=400 
height=200></canvas>
    <div>
<button id="save">Save</button>

<button id="clear">Clear</button>
</div>'

?>
 <script type="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/signature_pad/1.5.3/signature_pad.min.js"></script> <script> var signaturePad = new 
 SignaturePad(document.getElementById('signature-pad'), {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
  penColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
});
var saveButton = document.getElementById('save');
var cancelButton = document.getElementById('clear');

saveButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var data = signaturePad.toDataURL('image/png');

// Send data to server instead...
  window.open(data);
});

cancelButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  signaturePad.clear();
});    </script> </script><script src="touchpadjs.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was wrong, the js file was not being accessed by the html and css code  so i just added all the code into the php function as with  for javascript and  for css and it all started working.

Answer (score 0):

you output the HTML code snippet `echo '<canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200></canvas>'` once approved. You can include JS files in your webpage already or you can include it under above code as `<script type="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/signature_pad/1.5.3/signature_pad.min.js"></script>` followed by your own JS code `<script src="Path_to_your_own_JS_file"></script>`

Example code is already present on the same link at the bottom:

https://jsfiddle.net/szimek/d6a78gwq/

Comment: Thanks for the fast response but i am still a little confused. The sample code shows css, html, and javascript. Do i write 3 seperate files in 3 different formats and then put <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad" width=400 height=200></canvas> in the function above? Thanks Again!

Comment: You start slow and then you'll reach your desired output. You have to include JS file in the browser in order for signature pad to run. Are you able to put external JS files (internal or CDN hosted)?

Comment: I edited my answer. Does that make sense? Let me know if you need assistance on where you are missing the point.

Comment: i added a javascipt file wiwth my code in it and put the path in the place mentioned above and did the echo, and places <script type="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/signature_pad/1.5.3/signature_pad.min.js"></script> but it didnt work

Comment: You are missing your own JS code file which  wires up Signature pad code with your HTML.

Comment: so i am using cpanel i just put my javascript file in cpanel and wrote the path in <script src="Path_to_your_own_JS_file">

Comment: Yes how did that render?

Comment: if you dont mind could you please explain again i am confused

Comment: the html code is showing but the javascript is not working with it'

Comment: Do javascript load? That is CDN code and your own code which should have replica of JSFiddle code posted in this post?

Comment: I edited my post to show how i did it also the cide in the do it yourself script is also in the file i uploaded to the cpanel.

Comment: All the code that you got here will go in touchpadjs.js file. What if your rendered output? Rendered HTML

Comment: could you please crerate and send me the touchpadjs.js file you want me to upload to cpanel and also show the code to put in the approve function and i will try that because i am having a little trouble understanding what you mean.